# How to get the list of dropdown menu in excel - Python (openpyxl)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I need to get the list of all items of dropdown menu in excel file. When I was searching for this in google, I found just how to create a dropdown menu. I also didn't find this in openpyxl docs.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to obtain this from the formula variable in a data validation object. It may show either the values or the location where the values reside.

Example; Open workbook and create a data-validation object then extract the formula variable;

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb = load_workbook("workbook.xlsx")

for ws in wb:
    print(ws.title)
    for dv in ws.data_validations.dataValidation:
        if dv.type == 'list':
            print("List Cell: " + str(dv.cells))
            print("List Data: " + str(dv.formula1))
```

Output; List Cell is the cell where the list resides and List Data either the actual list of items, first output or the range where the list of items is located.

```
Sheet1
List Cell: B1
List Data: "open,high,low,close"

List Cell: B3
List Data: $E$2:$H$2


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: It seems it should work but for my cell I get: List Cell: AB4:AB500002
List Data: name27, I dont fully understand what does it mean

Comment: AB4:AB500002 means you have a drop down list in cells AB4 and AB5 (00002 I think just means the range size i.e. 2). It seems that both lists hold one source value, 'name27'.

Comment: What is 'source value'? There are a lot of values in excel which I can choose

Comment: As shown in the answer as 'List Data'. Source value is either the location of the values for the list or the actual values themselves.